# Attack speed messing up animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```csharp
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    if (currentanim >= 3)
    {
        currentanim = 1;
    }
    
    if (swordanimactive == false)
    {
        if (swordblockanimactive == 1)
        {
          currentanim = currentanim + 1;
          //the problem seems to be here
          Swordcontroller.speed = attackspeed;
          Swordcontroller.SetInteger("attackindex", currentanim); 
          Swordcontroller.SetTrigger("attack");     
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I set the attack speed over 1 (regular speed), after a few clicks it just stops working. I have no idea what causes this and I don't know how to fix it since I just implemnted this new animation system. Also, the current animation is just because there are 3 sword animations. However, if I set it to only one animation it works perfectly fine. When I use 3 different animations it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not really know how you set up the animator, but I recommend this structure.

[Multi Animation Animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKVVs.png)

[Has Exit Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2SJw.png)

Comment: Hey yeah. Sorry for not updating but that's the system I implemented. I don't remember what I did to fix but I think it had to do with the idle animation being Stuck. I ended up solving it though

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create some dataType like

```
public class MeleeAttackInstance
{
  public string animationName;
  public float animationSpeed;
  public float modifiedSpeed;

  public void ApplySpeedModifier(int queCount)
  {
    animationSpeed*(queCount +1);
  }
}
```

And make a queue of this attacks. When craracter should attack, you place item in queue and get the top one applying modified speed.